# How to grant permission for am administrator account in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, permissions

I installed SQL Server 2012 on my laptop. I am trying to run a script to create a simple database.

SQL Server version: 11.0.3128

SSMS starting parameters:

```
server type: database engine
server name: BOGLENETWORK\SQLEXPRESS
Authentication: Windows Authentication
user name:boglenetwork\admin121
```

I did some online search and it seems like The account I used doesn't have proper permission to write to the folder in which .mdf and .ldf file should be held. I would like to know do I check the account permission and make necessary modification the the file can be created in the destination folder. Thank for you advise and help!

[forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/a0b772f0-5e46-4b40-9363-bdc95853c89b) on a similar issue.

I received the follow message:

> *Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\saledat.mdf" failed with 
>   the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>
>   Msg 1802, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.*

Here is the code I am using to create the database:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE sales
ON 
( NAME = sales_dat,
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\saledat.mdf',
    SIZE = 10,
    MAXSIZE = 50,
    FILEGROWTH = 5 )
LOG ON
( NAME = sales_log,
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\salelog.ldf',
    SIZE = 5MB,
    MAXSIZE = 25MB,
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB ) ;
GO
```

Comment: The account you used to start SSMS is irrelevant -- the database engine service account must have the required permissions in the file system. Does that path actually exist? Did you do something like change the service account, or play around with the folder permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I mis-typed the path name in this case. 
The correct folder name is `MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS` instead of `MSSQL11.MSSQLEXPRESS`.

After correcting the folder path, I was able to create the database. Thanks!